# Issues during wget of sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, ssl-certificate, sonarqube-ops

I am trying to install SonarQube server on Ubuntu14.04 system.
When I do
    `wget https://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.3.zip`
i am getting certificate error which says
`ERROR: cannot verify akamai.bintray.com's certificate, issued by ‘/C=NL/L=Amsterdam/O=Verizon Enterprise Solutions/OU=Cybertrust/CN=Verizon Akamai SureServer CA G14-SHA2’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.`

I have tried installing the certificate using openssl, still I am unable to get the binaries. I have also updated the ca-certificates using `update-ca-certificates`, but with no luck.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Why 5.3? 5.6.1 is LTS, and 6.0 is latest.

Comment: Our existing Sonar is based on 5.3. What I am trying is to automate the installation of sonarcube using Ansible. During this process, I get the certificate error.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround:

> https://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.3.zip

redirects to

```
https://akamai.bintray.com/4e/4e61ee3a01d5e447bcd64357df77e0377325c4a2bb5ceb2cdeb5a5d193443ba5?__gda__=exp=1471600642~hmac=2b041a2929611ac66b6e703c87e0f08a939a5f4cf7a2b9ffa2d7ba3e5a2d7f3e&response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22sonarqube-5.3.zip
```

which seems to be available over HTTP.

So you can try:

```
wget "http://akamai.bintray.com/4e/4e61ee3a01d5e447bcd64357df77e0377325c4a2bb5ceb2cdeb5a5d193443ba5?__gda__=exp=1471600642~hmac=2b041a2929611ac66b6e703c87e0f08a939a5f4cf7a2b9ffa2d7ba3e5a2d7f3e&response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22sonarqube-5.3.zip"
```